# Android Bluetooth scanning on Froyo HTC Desire

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-2.2-froyo

Hi: I'm Facing some problems while scanning for bluetooth devices on a HTC Desire with Android 2.2 (Froyo). Directly after device reboot, it works but when I try to scan again later I only get the following error message. Broadcasts like BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND and BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED are not received.

```
ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(106): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/7229/hci0
```

On Nexus One (Froyo) this problem does not occur. Are there any known issues about that?

Comment: I filed this issue also under http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/t/6fd3f7852cf37d20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion about this topic did not yet yield any outlook to future behavior of bluetooth visibility: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6348
At least there seems some (not yet tested by me) patch for the Cyanogenmod firmware: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6348#c59